# Exeception get inputStream from connection 404 responce and file not found exception?

Tags: java, android

I want to try download a file from resume in android studio, i have try my code with open stream and don't have any problem but in this code:

```
public void startStream2(Context context) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(file.getFileUrl());
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy ploicy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(ploicy);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        int downloaded = 0;
        BufferedOutputStream bout;
        f = new File(downloadPath, file.getName());
        if (f.exists()) {
            downloaded = (int) f.length();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + (f.length()) + "-");
        }
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");
        connection.connect();

        int response=((HttpURLConnection)connection).getResponseCode();
        Log.e(TAG, "startStream2: "+ response );
        if (response>399 && response<601){
            InputStreamReader sr;
            sr = new InputStreamReader(((HttpURLConnection) connection).getErrorStream(), "UTF-8");
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int bt = 0; (bt = sr.read()) != -1;) {
                builder.append((char)bt);
            }
            sr.close();
            Log.e(TAG, "startStream2: "+builder.toString());
        }
        InputStream inp=connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(inp);
        stream2 = (downloaded == 0) ? new FileOutputStream(f) : new FileOutputStream(f, true);
        bout = new BufferedOutputStream(stream2, 1024);
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        int x = 0;
        while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
            bout.write(data, 0, x);
            downloaded += x;
            int percent = ((int) downloaded * 100) / (int) Size;
            //set percent progress
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "startStream2: ",e );
    }
}
```

Error log:

> startStream2: 405 startStream2: 
>                                                                            405 Not Allowed
>
> ## 405 Not Allowed
>
> ---
>
> nginx
>
> startStream2: 
>                                                                                java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:242)

I have test the url before and don't have any problem with download from first or resume.
How can i resolve it?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

The problem is here. It changes the HTTP verb from GET to POST. You don't want to POST. You aren't sending any output. Remove it.

And if the response code isn't 200 you should not get the input stream, otherwise it will throw an exception. You can get the *error* stream if you want more info, but there *isn't* an input stream at this point.

You can also remove

```
connection.connect();
```

and

```
connection.setDoInput(true);
```

They don't do anything that doesn't already happen.

Comment: i send property it need do output dont need?

Comment: No. You only need `setDoOutput(true)` if you're going to call `getOutputStream()` and write something to it.

Comment: I asssume that means resolved by this answer. If there was a different resolution you should post it here for the benefit of others.And you should consider upvoting and/or accepting answers you find useful here.

Answer (score 0):

remove these lines

```
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally i have resolved it by this code:

```
public void startStream2(Context context) {
try {
    URL url = new URL(file.getFileUrl());
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy ploicy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(ploicy);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    int downloaded = 0;
    BufferedOutputStream bout;
    f = new File(downloadPath, file.getName());
    if (f.exists()) {
        downloaded = (int) f.length();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + (f.length()) + "-");
    }
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");

    int response=((HttpURLConnection)connection).getResponseCode();
    Log.e(TAG, "startStream2: "+ response );
    if (response>399 && response<601){
        InputStreamReader sr;
        sr = new InputStreamReader(((HttpURLConnection) connection).getErrorStream(), "UTF-8");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int bt = 0; (bt = sr.read()) != -1;) {
            builder.append((char)bt);
        }
        sr.close();
        Log.e(TAG, "startStream2: "+builder.toString());
    }
    InputStream inp=connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(inp);
    stream2 = (downloaded == 0) ? new FileOutputStream(f) : new FileOutputStream(f, true);
    bout = new BufferedOutputStream(stream2, 1024);
    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    int x = 0;
    while ((x = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
        bout.write(data, 0, x);
        downloaded += x;
        int percent = ((int) downloaded * 100) / (int) Size;
        //set percent progress
    }
}catch (Exception e){
    Log.e(TAG, "startStream2: ",e );
}
}
```

Thank a lot!

Comment: This provides no explanation, and merely repeats what other answers have already stated.